# Autofocus not working in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to autofocus an element inside a ngfor loop.

Here is my chat.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let chat of chats; let last = last">
  {{ chat.chat }} <span *ngIf="last;" autofocus></span>
</div>
```

Actualy, by using button click i'm showing this chat popup, i need to autofocus the last chat.

My chat.ts file

```
import {  Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lsidebar',
  templateUrl: './lsidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lsidebar.component.css']
})

export class LsidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  chat:String;
  showChat:Boolean;
  chats:any[];
  fanmateId:String;
  socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.showFans = false;
    this.showChat = false;
    this.getFanmates();
    this.chatss();
  }


  getChat(fanmateId,name){
    this.showChat = !this.showChat;
    this.chatname = name;
    this.fanmateId = fanmateId;
    const temp = {
        fanmate_id: fanmateId
    }
    this.getChats(temp);

  }
  getChats(temp){
    this.chats = [];
    this.authService.getChat(temp);

  }
  chatss(){
    this.socket.on('chatRes',function(chats){

      this.chats = chats.chats[0].messages;

    }.bind(this));

    this.socket.on('addChat',function(chats){

      this.chat = '';
      // console.log(chats);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

is there any suggestions to end up my search on this autofocus on google for angular 4.

Comment: Can you add your ts code as well..!

Comment: Thanks @dheeraj,i added my ts code..

Answer (score 0):

`autofocus` attribute works on `<button>, <input>, <keygen>, <select>` and `<textarea>`. Read this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp).

You need to set a `tabindex` attribute on your `span` and focus it manually in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

```
<div *ngFor="let chat of chats; let last = last">
  {{ chat.chat }} 
  <span *ngIf="last;" #lastChat tabindex="9999"></span>
</div>
```

In you `ts` code:

```
@ViewChild('lastChat') lastChat:HTMLElement;
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.lastChat.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbxxrb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Hi faisal, When i run this, it says "property nativeElement does not exist on type HTMLElement"

Comment: Is the tabindex property really necessary?

Answer (score -1):

set tabindex to the element and focus it in your ts fil